# I'm trying to do a blackjack in python

Tags: python, blackjack

I am in the process of doing blackjack, but I have a problem.
I don't know how to do that if I want him to print for example the Q to print it as str, but when adding the player's hand I take it as a 10.

The error it gives me is: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

The code I have is:

````
jugador = []
dealer = []
deck = ['A' ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'K', 'Q']

for card in deck:
    if card == 'J':
        card = 10 
    elif card == 'K':
        card = 10
    elif card == 'Q':
        card = 10

while len(jugador) != 2:                            
    random.choice(deck)
    card = random.choice(deck)
    jugador.append(card)
    if card == 'A':
        card = 11
    print(jugador)
    if sum(jugador) > 11:
        print("Hola")```
````

Comment: you could have two lists, one with the cards' representation (`"A", 2, 3...`) and another one with the values. Or you could have a dictionary, where the keys are the representations and the values are, well, the values.
Side note: `"A"` can either have a value of 1 or 11 depending on the situation. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are two values you want to track: Name and effective value. Your code currently tries to track them in one variable. Try using either different variables to track Name vs Value or try defining and using a class to capture these details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade some things in your code for example the deck contains 4 cards of each number, so you should add that. You can also use a dictionary to represent the deck :

`deck = {'A': 1, '2': 2, ..., 'K': 10}`

Note that in the dictionary the keys are strings and their values are integers. You should also remove the first random.choice(deck) because you stored the random value in the card variable and dont forget to remove the card you picked for the player.